# HTML form with 'get' link without equal signs

Tags: php, html, forms, get

In my page I have `GET` form with several checkboxes. Each `checkbox` has different name and value of 1.

Submit button generates url like this: `localhost/page.php?a=1&b=1`.

I'm checking whether `checkbox` is on with PHP function `isset($_GET['a'])`.

Some testing revealed that typing in address bar url `localhost/page.php?a&b` also works.
Is there any way to make that such link will be generated instead of first one?

Setting checkboxes' value to `""` doesn't work - it preserves `"="` sign.

Maybe I should edit `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a really convoluted approach, you could use javascript to cancel the submit request and then redirect to the location using just the checked input names. I think it might look something like:

```
<form action="page.php" method="get" id="page_form">
    <label for="a">Checkbox A</label><input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<script>
  var page_form = document.getElementById("page_form");
  page_form.onsubmit = forward_request;

function forward_request() {

  var inputs = document.getElementById("page_form").elements;
  var clean_query_string = "?";
  for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       if(inputs[i].checked) {
            clean_query_string += inputs[i].name + "&";
       }
  }

  window.location = document.getElementById("page_form").action + clean_query_string;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was solution of that I was thinking, however it doesn't work when Javascript is disabled..

Comment: That gives what he already has: "page.php?a&b". And appends "&" if only one element is checked.

Comment: this is true. but if javascript is disabled, it will just submit the form and those users see an ugly address, which doesn't change the actual result. that'll teach em

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch - Nooo, he wants "page.php?a&b" instead of "page.php?a=1&b=1". and I was so exhausted after writing and testing that code off the top of my head, i figured the OP could worry about how to trim off the trailing `&` on his own, since it's trivial.

Comment: @Anthony Oh, sure, forgot that submit button won't be canceled. Anyway, I need to write one more function which checks checkboxes from URL when it is typed manually (or entered from bookmark).
Not so complicated, however it should run after page loaded and checkboxes will be checked after some time.

Comment: allright then - i guess teamwork brought us nearer (is that correct english, hmm? ) to a solution :)

Comment: Won't some aggressive pop-up blockers block that `window.location` changing?

Comment: I think popup blockers generally only target window.popup and maybe `new window` I think they are generally more forgiving to js redirects that are same origin

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get rid of the equals sign on a GET request.

This only thing to change would be the "&", by modifying the PHP ini setting "arg_separator.output" to let's say ";".
That would give you `localhost/page.php?a=1;b=1`. 
That's not what you want.

By using .htaccess RewriteRules you might get something, like:

```
localhost/page/1/1
```

You could apply the following .htaccess rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./page.php
```

This rewrite rule just passes every URL to page.php (better index.php).

Example:

1. URL = `/page/a/b` OR `/page/a&b` OR `/page/stuff/a/otherstuff&b#123`
2. rewriteRule is applied
3. passed forward to page.php
4. access REQUEST_URI to get URL string (/page/a/b)

Then you could grab the URL and process it like you want by splitting it:

```
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // <-- this gives you the url

// next steps are just string processing examples

#remove the directory you don't want
$request_uri = str_replace('part_not_wanted', '', $request_uri);

#split the path by '/'
$params     = split("/", $request_uri);

# or split by '&'
$params     = split("&", $request_uri);
```

Comment: It isn't possible to change `/` to `&` with RewriteRules?

Comment: Sure. Thats possible. I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: I can change checkboxes' value to their name. Then I will get link like `"localhost/page/a/b"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems like not working as I expected... So to use those `/` I shouldn't use submit buttons but use links? Links can be generated by Javascript. So I can generate link with no `=` using javascript and no RewriteRules.

Comment: .htaccess wouldn't care where the call comes from: "a href", "manually typed in url", "button". it just forwards the full URL - with / and & or other chars.

Comment: Likely I misunderstood how `GET` method works. I thought that browser simply concatenates form data to url and then send request with this url to server. It turn out that request is sent first and url is constructed using server rules?

Comment: Yes, lot's of magic is possible with server rules. Stuff like "url rewriting" and "url forwarding" by server rules. It's pretty powerful and common: just take a look at the stackoverflow URL :)

Comment: I have understood one thing - it's worth it learning those RewriteRules. Powerful thing as I see :) For now, I don't understand syntax of .htaccess, was using it only for denying opening some files...